# Finding the first empty row to paste a row from another sheet

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2003

I am working on a macro for copying rows for different locations to sheets specific to the locations from a master sheet.

I have everything working except finding the last row when the cell I am checking contains a '`0`' and shows as an empty string match. I need to either find a better way to paste to the first empty row, or to find out if the cell being checked is truly empty.

Here is the macro code:

```
Sub MoveDataToSheets()
'
' MoveDataToSheets Macro
' Macro written 2/25/2011 by Jim Snyder
'
    Dim rowCount As Integer, sheetIndex As Integer, LastRow As Integer
    Dim ExcelLastCell As Range

    ' Prevent screen updates from slowing execution
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    rowCount = ActiveCell.CurrentRegion.Rows.Count

    ' Process each row once copying row to matching location tab
    For currentRow = 1 To rowCount

        ' Determine which sheet the row goes to
        Select Case (Cells(currentRow, "B").Value)
            Case "ALTAVISTA"
                sheetIndex = 2
            Case "AN"
                sheetIndex = 3
            Case "Ballytivnan"
                sheetIndex = 4
            Case "Casa Grande"
                sheetIndex = 5
            Case "Columbus - Devices (DE)"
                sheetIndex = 6
            Case "Columbus - Nutrition"
                sheetIndex = 7
            Case "Fairfield"
                sheetIndex = 8
            Case "Granada"
                sheetIndex = 9
            Case "Guangzhou"
                sheetIndex = 10
            Case "NOLA"
                sheetIndex = 11
            Case "Process Research Operations (PRO)"
                sheetIndex = 12
            Case "Richmond"
                sheetIndex = 13
            Case "Singapore"
                sheetIndex = 14
            Case "Sturgis"
                sheetIndex = 15
            Case "Zwolle"
                sheetIndex = 16
            Case Else
                sheetIndex = 1
        End Select

        ' Only if the row cotains a valid location, copy it to location sheet
        If (sheetIndex > 1) Then
            Sheets(1).Activate                                       ' Activate the sheet being copied from
            ActiveSheet.Rows(currentRow).Copy                        ' Copy from master sheet
            Set sheet = Worksheets(sheetIndex)                       ' Designate target sheet
            Set ExcelLastCell = sheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlLastCell) ' Find the last used row
            LastRow = ExcelLastCell.Row
            If (sheet.Rows(LastRow).Cells(LastRow, 5).Value = "") Then
                sheet.Paste Destination:=sheet.Cells(LastRow, 1)     ' Paste into first row
            Else
                sheet.Paste Destination:=sheet.Cells(LastRow + 1, 1) ' Paste in first empty row
            End If
            Sheets(1).Activate                                       ' Activate the sheet being copied from
        End If
    Next

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Chip Pearson's site has an example of what you need. You can do this on each page prior to paste.
[Finding The Last Used Cell In A Range](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/LastCell.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your using Excel 2003 and/or you won't have more than 65,536 on any sheet:

```
LastRow = Sheet.Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row
```

Answer (score 0):

For just finding the last cell that has a value in a column:

```
Dim LastRow As Long
LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row
```

You can then use `LastRow` as a standard row reference. I often use it to find the last row then add 1, which actually gives me the first empty cell in that column. Example:

```
Cells(LastRow + 1, 6).Value = Cells(10, 3).Value 'Or whatever value you want
```

The CPearson site linked above by datatoo however does list many more ways to find "last cells" if you are looking for more complicated solutions.

Edit: Just tested to be sure: this *does* detect 0s or nulls ( ="" ) in the column.